# What is the penalty for running out of HP in Monster Manor?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-mansion-monster-manor

In Monster Manor (a.k.a. StreetPass Mansion), what are the consequences of running out of HP? Do you have to start the game over, or do you lose some amount of progress, or what?

So far I've only seen one serious fight and I'm on the fourth floor, but I don't know how cautious I should be.

Comment: (Yes, that's a tag that ought to be a synonym, but which one? See [meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7494/mii-plaza-mini-games-have-different-names-worldwide-than-in-the-us-can-the-tags).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run out of HP, you basically "quit" — it will end your session, and take you back to the title page, and you won't get to use any other Miis or the like that you collected that day. Every session starts with full HP.

Answer (score 4):

Only the sessions where you died the previous time start with full HP.  Otherwise, you'll just have whatever HP you had at the end of the previous session.  The exception, of course, is that your HP refills any time you go up a floor.  And, of course, when your HP hits zero, that session immediately ends.